# Why do we call it Bayes' theorem?

Tags: probability, math-history

I'm not a historian, nor would I claim to be one, but I've seen a lot of people say that it was Laplace who formalized the theorem:

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$$

Why don't we call it "Laplace's Theorem"?

Is there a technical or serious reason for continuing to give Bayes the credit?

I don't mean to be obstinate in asking this question, I'm honestly curious if there is a technical or serious answer to the question outside "Bayes was the first to come to the idea".

Comment: What did Google return when you entered "why do we call it bayes theorem"?

Comment: Perhaps for the same reason that many people call it Burnsides Lemma instead of "*The Lemma that is not Burnside's.*"  I'm not at home and so don't have access to my history books at the moment, but [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#History) seems to suggest a different story than what you suggest.

Comment: While we're at it, Stirling's formula shoud be called the De Moivre-Stirling formula.

Comment: By [french wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Bayes#Histoire), Laplace rediscovered the formula in 1774 (i.e. without knowing that it has been discovered by Bayes previously), whereas Bayes discovered it before 1761.

Comment: @JohnDouma I have googled that and it returns the wikipedia page.

Comment: This is not Bayes' theorem, but the *definition* of conditional probability.  Bayes' theorem yields a formula which links $P(A\mid B)$ and $P(B\mid A)$.

Comment: @JMoravitz In the second sentence it seems to state that Laplace "reproduced and extended" the result and that Bayesian interpretation was developed mainly by Laplace. Authors I've read Jaynes' and others have given a lot of credit to Laplace for this theorem.

Comment: Math is notorious for naming things after the wrong people, even if this isn't an example.

Comment: Although it is relatively rare as far as I know, there are occasions when the name associated with something is not necessarily that of the first person to discover it.  For example, with [Gilbreath's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbreath%27s_conjecture), "In 1878, eighty years before Gilbreath's discovery, François Proth had, however, published the same observations along with an attempted proof, which was later shown to be false". I don't know why it's not called Proth's conjecture instead. However, I believe this happens generally more rarely with theorems.

Comment: @Bernard I don't really see the difference in the two but okay I edited it to your formulation.

Comment: It is worth mentioning also that the names given to theorems are not necessarily decided at the time of publishing, or even in the same generation as the time of publishing.  Names given to theorems are sometimes done so in order to honor a particular person's work on the field.  There is an amusing anecdote I heard about Hilbert attending a talk someone else was giving and the speaker was referring to a Hilbert space.  Hilbert himself didn't call them that and was confused as to what a Hilbert space actually was and had to ask.

Comment: The logical difference between a definition and a formula that has to be proved (even if it is a simple observation).

Comment: I guess the answer here is that it's likely that we give Bayes' the theorem because he was the first to write a paper about the phenomenon. I really doubt he was the first to come to the idea. Anyways thank you all for contributing. I was just curious and I wasn't satiated with the wikipedia page.

Comment: [Stigler's law of eponymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler%27s_law_of_eponymy) states that no scientific discovery is named after its original discoverer. (Note that Stigler's law was originally discovered by Robert Merton.)

Comment: This would be better suited for [History of Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Wojowu wow I didn't know they had started that forum

Comment: See the ["Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics"](http://jeff560.tripod.com/b.html) entries for "Bayes" and "Bayes's Theorem".

Comment: Just pointing out that Pythagoras' theorem was in use well over $1000$ years before Pythagoras. (Presumably it's named after him because he wrote down a proof for it, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thomas Bayes died in 1761, and his "Bayes Theorem" was published in the  Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society of London in 1763 after his death.

Indeed, Laplace first wrote down the general formula, but it was Thomas Bayes who first derived the special case of Laplace's general formula. One of the reasons why it is called Bayes Theorem might be that Laplace genuinely acknowledged Bayes's important contribution.

Here is what Laplace wrote:

"Bayes, in the Transactions Philosophiques of the Year 1763, sought directly the probability that the possibilities indicated by past experiences are comprised within given limits; and he has arrived at this in a refined and very ingenious manner, although a little perplexing."

Information from [Bayes, Laplace and Bayes’ Theorem](https://telescoper.wordpress.com/2014/10/01/bayes-laplace-and-bayes-theorem/)

Comment: This is a good answer and mostly what I was looking for in asking the question. This is the first instance I've read that Laplace had any knowledge of Bayes' work.  Thank you.